# How to setup nginx to return Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate for html files only?

Tags: nginx, server

I have nginx server and want to prevent caching my website html files. How can i achieve this?

Additionally i want to ask where is nginx server config as usual located?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content to `0` as below which tells the browser to always load content from the web server

`<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">`

Nginx config are located in `/etc/nginx/` by default

Comment: Are you sure this will work despite web server config? I doubt. 
If a server will respond with another expires? I have some meta tags which tries to control caching of HTML files, it seems they not always work.

Answer (score 0):

With

`ps -ef | grep nginx`

you can find the nginx master process and see which config file it has loaded

to set an header, that disables caching of html use this:

```
location ~* \.(html)$ {
    add_header        Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate";
}
```